# DEV C++ : No error while compiling any program but it is not running

Tags: dev-c++

All are working fine with `DEV C++`. Suddenly it stop working well. Program is compiling with no `error` messages. But when i hit `run` button nothing is happened. This is happening with all `program`. So there is no issue with `program`.

This was also happen earlier with me. Then i reinstall `DEV C++` then it worked fine. But after sometimes it started again. I don't want to reinstall again and again. Currently I'm using `window 10.`

Any help will be great. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved. It was my avast who is blocking the application to launch. Avast is considering the application as a false positive means as a threat to the system(false).

Avast was wrong it was not a threat for the system. That's why it is a false positive. Then i add an exception(rule) to avast not to scan a particular file/folder. But this is also not working well.